# How to tokenize a string using indexOf and substring methods

Tags: java, tokenize

So I have to tokenize a string, and I can only use these 2 methods to tokenize
I have the base, but I don't know what to put in,
My friend did it, but I forgot how it looked, it went something like this
I remember he split it using the length of a tab

```
public class Tester
{
private static StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer ("The cat in the hat");
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sb.length() ; i++)
    {
        int tempIndex = sb.indexOf(" ", 0);
        sb.substring(0,tempIndex);
        if(tempIndex > 0) 
        {
            System.out.println(sb.substring(0,tempIndex));
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you giving up? Read the javadoc of `String`. Then think about how you would do it on pen and paper. Which characters do you need to look for?

Comment: @ Juned: I can't use that method, only these 2

Comment: @JunedAhsan - You mean, you couldn't write a split method using indexOf and substring???????

Comment: Think!!  If you need to split at spaces, find a space, then substring the part up to (but not including) the space, discard the space, then repeat.

Comment: I've edited it by memory, but I know its not right, any ideas

Comment: (And I'll downvote anyone who give an outright code answer to this.  The OP is supposed to *learn* and he won't learn if code is just handed to him.)

Comment: What does `sb.indexOf('    ', );` do??  (Answer, absolutely nothing, other than perhaps throw an exception.)

Comment: You do know how to find the [documentation for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), right??

Comment: @HotLicks Is my answer ok? I tried to help without giving the answer...

Comment: @AnubianNoob - I wouldn't have gone as far, but I tend to try perhaps a little too hard to get the OP to actually do some work.

Comment: @user3678006 Have you considered looking into a while loop as opposed to a for?

Answer (score 1):

`String.indexOf(int ch)` returns the index of a character. If you do `sb.indexOf(' ')` you'll get the first index of a space. You can use that in conjunction with `substring()`: `sb.substring(0,sb.indexOf(' ')-1)` will get you your first token.

This seems like a homework problem, so I don't want to give you the full answer, but you probably can work it out. Comment if you need more help.

Comment: it gives me an outofBounds exception, here is the code

Comment: You might have to subtract 1?

Comment: @user3678006 Anyway, as HotLicks said, I'm leaving this up to you to figure out. Think, read the documentation, and work your way through it. It will make you a better programmer.

Comment: still gives same exception

Comment: @user3678006 - Keep in mind that the very last indexOf will return a negative number, since the space will not be found.  So you shouldn't literally say `sb.substring(0,sb.indexOf(' ')-1)`, but should save the result of the indexOf operation in a temp, test it with an `if` statement, and only use the value if it's positive.

Comment: @user3678006 - And in general, especially while you're learning, don't write stuff as `sb.substring(0,sb.indexOf(' ')-1)`, but break into individual steps with temp vars to store the intermediate results.  Then you can easily examine those intermediate results to debug your program.

Comment: what is a temp, and how would I do it

Comment: "Temp" means "temporary variable" -- simply a variable that is used locally to store a value for a line or two.  For instance, you might examine the spec for `indexOf` and see that it returns an `int`, so you'd do `int tempIndex = sb.indexOf(' ');` or some such.  ("tempIndex" is any name you choose.)  Then in the next line you might do `if (tempIndex >= 0) {` to decide if you found a blank or not.

Comment: @user3678006 - It sounds like you need to back off a bit.  Just write a simple program that adds some numbers together and prints them.  Write a program that uses `substring` to split a String at a hard-coded point, etc.

Comment: I have tried, but it only displays one word, when I delete the string from 0 to 4, it displays the cat in he instead of the string I want it to display

Comment: @user3678006 - OK, a hint:  After you take the first word, what's left in `sb`?  Exactly what you had before, since you haven't changed it.  You need to use `substring` again to select only the text AFTER the space (and assign that back to `sb`), so you can continue with the same loop.  Or, use the flavor of `indexOf` which lets you specify a starting point, to continue searching from the last blank.  Print out what you have each time you loop, so you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If your are familiar with a while loop construct you can take a look at my pseudocode, should be within the constraints of your problem:

```
String text = "texty text text"

while(TextHasASapce){
     print text up to space
     set text to equal all text AFTER the space 
}
print ??
```

Using your two allowed methods the above is convertible line by line to what you are after.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Each line in that segment I typed can be replaced by a line of code.  Each sentence in my example says what that line of code needs to do, you just need swap my text for the relevant coding.  For example where I have put while(TextHasASpace){ the TextHasASpace needs to be replaced by some code which checks if the text contains any spaces

Comment: I lost, Im just having trouble sparating now, output displays

Comment: @user3678006 There are a couple of ways your task can be done, Anubian Noob has gone one way, I have gone another.  If you wanna try my way I suggest you note what I wrote in my answer somewhere (either on some paper or in your question code, then try slowly line by line to convert to code).  I will try and help where I can

Comment: Ive checked for text has space methods, but none of the ones I found have worked, and how would I replace my text, I delete it each time

Comment: Ok, let's got at it 1 line at a time.  the first part, TextHasASpace.  In your question you listed 2 methods, indexOf, and Substring.  One of those will return a value telling you if the text has a space.  Which one? and what does it return

Comment: indexOf returns a value telling if I have a space I think

Comment: I think the problem is with the delete, as it deletes 4 elements

Comment: Correct!  Now we want to check if there are any spaces in the text.  The best way to do that is to have our while loop run whilst indexOf does not return -1 (Which would mean there is no space).  So we need a condition that says indexOf(Aspace) in the text is not equal to -1. What would that condition be?